# How do I setup & use the artifactory features provided by GitLab

Tags: gradle, gitlab-ci, artifacts

I have looked up various Q&A's on how to use the artifactory features offered by GitLab, and they all talk about either JFrog (a.k.a Artifactory) or Nexus or something else. GitLab says that we could use it as Artifact management, and I was able to generate artifacts. But I am stuck now since I am completely lost on how to use this.

Here is the script I use to generate artifact using Gradle:

```
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/libs/*.jar
```

Can anyone guide me on how I could refer to an artifact in my repo during CI/CD. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can read up on them in the [**dependencies**](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#dependencies) section of the Gitlab docs. Some quotes to guide you:

> Note that artifacts from all previous stages are passed by default.

So every **artifact** you build in a **prior job** of the **same pipeline** is passed by default.

> (...) the artifacts from `job:x` will be downloaded and extracted in
>   the context of the build.

In the context of the build means relative to the working path of the job.

To test this, add a job after the one you create the artifact in and add a `ls -la` command in the next job to see what has been extracted and is ready for use.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Stefan van Gastel. I read this and understand a single .gitlabxi.yml containing dependencies. I am thinking if one repo (say, base) generates and artifact, then another repo's .gitlab-ci.yml should be able to reference the base artifact, How would I do that?
(Not sure if I am misunderstanding anything here)